# Datasheet XR2981

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet

Does somebody know where the datasheet of this chip XR2981 is? Available also on AliExpress.

[image]

Comment: Ask the seller. It's their intention to sell you something. If they can't organize a datasheet for the circuit, they're selling you something with specifications they have no chance nor intent to keep. Just keep away.

Comment: It's a XR2981. Likely a clone of other 2981 chips which do have data sheets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a datasheet:

https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/1829407826904960/Xysemi_XR2981.pdf

It was included in the files of [this Hackaday project](https://hackaday.io/project/182940/files).

Comment: Cool! thanks to all.